# How can I improve a wiki-like link in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have a Rails application that I'm doing text editing and allowing wiki-like links. I've been able to get it working so you can write [[:slug]] in a description and it will generate the link for the associated page with the link text being the name that's saved in the database. I'd like to make it so that I can write [[:slug | Some Text]] and the link will say "Some Text" instead of the name. Also I'd like to make it optional to include custom link text.

Here's the code that I'm using.

```
def replace_slugs(text)
  slugs = text.scan(/\[{2}:([^\]]*)\]{2}/).map{|s|s[0]}
  Character.where(:slug => slugs).each{|ch| text.gsub!("[[:#{ch.slug}]]",
    link_to(ch.name, adventure_character_path(ch.adventure, ch)))}
  return text
end
```

Comment: You could use [Regexp Capture Groups](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#label-Capturing) and extract the slug as well as the link_title from there.

Comment: @ThomasKlemm Thanks for the link, that really helped. I'll post the answer I came up with. I'd like to give you +1 on your comment, but I'm totally new to this site. How do I boost your rating?

Comment: Thanks man. You can upvote comments as soon as some of your answers receive upvotes and you are across a certain threshold. It would be great if you could post your working solution as an answer below so that people can learn from it.

Comment: Ok, I'll check back tomorrow and upvote. I posted the answer I came up with about the same time you commented, so it's there for anyone else to adapt to their own projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research on regexp for Rails and string scanning, I've come up with an answer to my question. Here's the code for the method I'm using now:

```
def replace_slugs(text, characters)
  # Regexp that will recognize wiki urls with pipes and return 2 items
  # It also ignores wiki urls that don't have a pipe
  # /\[\[:([^|\]]*)?\|([^\]]+)\]\]/
  links = text.scan(/\[\[:([^|\]]*)?\|([^\]]+)\]\]/)
  for link in links do
    slug = link[0]
    title = link[1]

    # I'm stripping out the whitespace when I do my find and for my link
    # This makes it so you can have whitespace before and after the pipe
    # e.g. [[:slug|Title]] [[:slug | Title]] [[:slug   |   Title]]
    ch = characters.find_by_slug(slug.strip)
    text.gsub!("[[:#{slug}|#{title}]]", link_to(title.strip,
      adventure_character_path(ch.adventure, ch))) if ch
  end

  slugs = text.scan(/\[{2}:([^\]]*)\]{2}/).map{|s|s[0]}
  characters.where(:slug => slugs).each{|ch| text.gsub!("[[:#{ch.slug}]]",
    link_to(ch.name, adventure_character_path(ch.adventure, ch)))}
  return text
end
```

Because of the way I formulated the regexp, I had to make two separate calls for when there are both links of form [[:slug]] and [[:slug|Title]]. Because of that, I've added an extra variable in the method called characters. This is so I can pass in an array of characters from where I call the method instead of having to search the entire database as that could get expensive and I already know the list of characters I want to use.